# Function to compare structures in order to sort a list

Tags: c, list, structure, abstraction

I have an abstract data type in C, LIST OF THINGS, ist node has a void* pointer, what i'm trying to do is create a function to compare an specific field of different structures in order to sort my list of things.

```
typedef struct node{
     char *name;
     void *thing;
     struct node *next;   
}Node;
```

This is the node i'm working with, i've already created a list of integers, list of structures and te compare function for both, but i can't figure out how to do a compare function to diferent structures.  for example:

given these types:

```
 typedef struct main{
   float weight; 
   char*model; 
   float maxspeed; 
}Main;


typedef struct airplane{
   float weight; 
   float maxspeed; 
  }Airplane; 

typedef struct car{
   char*model;  
   float maxspeed;  
}Car;
```

And this is the function, so you have an idea of what i'm trying to do, it doesn't work, Main has fields that doesn't exist in either one or the other structure.

```
int comparefunction(void*a,void*b){
   Main a1, a2; 
   a1=*(Main*)a;  
   a2=*(Main*)b; 

   return a1.weight-a2.weight; 
}
```

This function(doesn't work)  is passed as a paremeter to the function that links the nodes in order to use the comparefunction.

```
//insert prototype: 
 //insert(Node*listp,Node*newp,int(*func_comp)(void*,void*));  

list=insert(list,newItem(&car1),comparefunction); 
list=insert(list,newItem(&airplane1),comparefunction); 
list=insert(list,newItem(&airplane2),comparefunction);
```

How can i do to compare a single field of two or more different structures? assuming that i know what each structure contains

Answer (score 0):

Well, your `car` struct *doesn't have* a `weight` field, so I'm not exactly sure what you're trying to accomplish here. If you had your `car` struct look like

```
typedef struct car {
    float weight;
    char* model;
    float maxspeed;
} Car;
```

I think your function would work. Note, it is important that the member that you want to compare is at the same offset into each struct **including the `Main` struct**.

**EDIT**

[This does work](http://ideone.com/j9EdgO).

**Another edit based on comments**

You can't compare two completely unrelated things. This is not a technical deficiency with C. It just does not logically make any sense to compare for example an `Airplane` and an `int`.

Comment: the assignment is to create an heterogenous list and to be able to compare the structures so i can insert the nodes in order no matter if the structures are not equal, i could even have a node with just an int and i have to be able to compare it with a structure and return and int as a result of the comparisson

Comment: @user2943683 That doesn't make any sense. How do you compare an `airplane` and an `int`?

Comment: is a list of things, of anything!

Comment: @user2943683 You can make a list of things. But you can't compare two completely unrelated things.  What would you want the result of a compare function to be when you pass in an `Airplane` and an `int`?

Comment: is not the entire structure, is a field of the structure! this is an asignment from my university, i made my ADT list of things, now i have to use it as a programmer. for example lets say a node has a structure with a field "value" and another node just points a value and all the other nodes of my list have an element named "value", and i want to sort the list by that value! is completely up to me how to order the list, but it has to be heterogenous... if all of my nodes  contain the same it's too easy! i don't know if you understand me now!

Comment: @user2943683 I understand what you're saying. And my original answer stands. If the structs do not have the field at the same offset, then what you are trying to do is impossible. If they are at the same offset, then the solution that you tried would work.

Comment: @user2943683 you are trying to pass a car and an airplane into your comparison function and comparing their weights, but cars don't have a weight according to your struct.

Comment: if a structure lacks the field, it should go to the end of the list and the compare function should not take it in count! if my professor did it i think so can i... i just don't know how!

Comment: @user2943683 I'm not saying that what your professor told you to do is impossible. I'm saying what you claim to be trying to do is impossible. Somehow you have either failed to understand or failed to properly convey what you are trying to accomplish. So until you are able to clarify it, we won't be able to help you.

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to compare *somewhat* similar things, you can look into unions.

```
struct attributes{
    float weight;
    // other common things?
};

struct thing {
    enum { Car, Main, Airplane } type;
    struct attributes attrs;
    union {
        struct Car car;
        struct Main main;
        struct Airplane airplane;
    } other_thing;
};
```

You'd change your list to store the thing struct, which is a structure that encapsulates all your possible types. The common elements of each type are extracted to the attributes struct. Your compare function would then operate on the attributes struct of the thing struct. The union is used here to only create enough space within struct thing for the largest of the union elements, so that you're not wasting space storing all three structs and only using one.